# CardLayout doesn't show JButtons when I add static to arraylist with JButtons

Tags: java, swing, static, jbutton, cardlayout

I don't know what is wrong, but it's very interesting. I made code with `CardLayout` and panels. On panel with `CardLayout` I put `JButton`s from `ArrayList` and it is working...

It's looking like this:
[image]

Panel with `CardLayout` is on the bottom with pink `JButton`s.....part of my code is

```
public class Controller extends JPanel {

ArrayList<JButton> tnp=new ArrayList<JButton>();
ArrayList<JButton> sokp=new ArrayList<JButton>();
ArrayList<JButton> alkp=new ArrayList<JButton>();


CardLayout cardlayout=new CardLayout();
JPanel cardpanel = new JPanel(cardlayout);
```

but, when I add static to `ArrayList` like this:

```
static ArrayList<JButton> tnp=new ArrayList<JButton>();
static ArrayList<JButton> sokp=new ArrayList<JButton>();
static ArrayList<JButton> alkp=new ArrayList<JButton>();
```

my applicaton look like this:

[image]

As you can see, program still shows panel with CardLayout, (border with `red` ) but JButtons from

```
static ArrayList<JButton> tnp=new ArrayList<JButton>();
static ArrayList<JButton> sokp=new ArrayList<JButton>();
static ArrayList<JButton> alkp=new ArrayList<JButton>();
```

lost! why?

I don't unerstand. One ArrayList is for one panel with cardlayout, that panel is for all JTabbedPane, and I want to have access to that list from another class (that is why I want to be static), to add or remove buttons to that panel. But I can't, nothing adds to that arraylist .

Comment: u need to add each object to this `Layout`

Comment: A `JButton` cannot be added to more than one panel.

Comment: Mind the parent-child relationship!

Comment: I don't unerstand. One ArrayList is for one `panel` with cardlayout, that panel is for all JTabbedPane, and I want to have access to that list from another class (that is why I want to be static), to add or remove buttons to that `panel`. But I can't, nothing  adds to that arraylist

Comment: `static` is rarely a solution (and more commonly a problem or an indication of faulty design).  Why did you change them to `static`?

Comment: Because I want to add or remove JButtons to that ArrayList from another class. Is there another way,to have access to `ArrayList` from another class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static field is a field that belongs to the class it's declared in. Whereas an instance (non-static) field belongs to an instance of the class it's declared in.

So, if you have the following:

```
public class Controller {
    public static List<JButton> staticList = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    public List<JButton> instanceList = new ArrayList<JButton>();

    ...
}
```

and the following user code:

```
Controller c1 = new Controller();
Controller c2 = new Controller();
```

each controller has its own instance list, but they both share a unique static list.

You want every controller to have its own buttons, so you definitely don't want static lists.

If you want to have access to a controller from another object, you simply need to pass the controller to this other class instance:

```
Controller c1 = new Controller();
OtherClass other = new OtherClass(c1);
```

And inside `OtherClass`, you can do whatever you want with the controller:

```
private Controller theController;

public OtherClass(Controller controller) {
    this.theController = theController;
}

public void foo() {
    // call any method you want from theController
}
```

Comment: So, I make another class just for access list from class Controller, and I can do it with method foo? Thanks, I hope I can do it, I am a little confuse.

Comment: No, you don't make another class just for accessing the list. YOU asked how to access the list of a controller from another class, and the above shows you how to do.

Comment: I got it. But I have class Application in which I made object Controller and object of class Table, in class Table I made button , when I press it it make object of class   JOptionPaneMultiInput in that class I need access to Controller, so I need to make JOptionPaneMultiInput(controller). Am I right? And how to connect all this classes

Comment: Do I have to all this classes make private Controller theController; and to all it's constructor pass it?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Just as you would pass a real object (a phone for example) to someone in order to let it use it, you pass a reference to a controller to other objects in order for them to let them use the controller.

Comment: Thank you! I did it, you saved me much time to understand!